# WCF nettcp binding on LAN with system on workgroup

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, lan

I have a WCF service which is hosted in a Windows Service and has net.tcp endpoint. It is working fine when we have server and clients in the same domain. I am having problem when both server and clients are in the same LAN but on Workgroup. Could some how i can able to communicate on workgroup using nettcpbinding.

Comment: When in a domain, firewall rules are managed by the security policy and allows connections to other domain resources.  In a workgroup this is not the case, so you have to open up firewall ports manually or disable the firewall.

Comment: I have open the firewall port on which communication is taking place

Comment: Atlast I were able to communicate via help of security mode="None" in both client and server settings.

Comment: Yes, the default communication mode for netTcp is Transport security, so it's looking for Windows identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I were able to communicate on system in workgroup by remoing security.
Mean's Setting sercurity to None on both Client and server in case of work group environment. for Domain environment i used same old security settings.

Answer (score 0):

please dont touch server section of your binding.you need to modify client side.

add this codes to your channel :

```
channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = "username";
channel.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = "password";
```